# Footer multi-line alignment for KOMA class

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, koma-script

I want to produce multi-line footers with precise spacing control. I wanted to use a combination of `parbox` and `raisebox` to define the footer exactly, however, I've noticed some placement issue. I'm using a construct such as (with scrlayer-scrpage, raisebox is not needed for this example):

```
\ifoot{foo\parbox[b]{5cm}{bar\\baz}}
```

this leads to foo and bar being aligned, which I want, foo is not placed on the correct location in the footer. I turned on `showframe` with geometry to show the issue.
[image: Issue with multiple lines]

With only one line, the behaviour is as expected:
[image: Correct for one line]

I would have expected that a third line would add to the shift, but this actually just "normally" stacks on the lower line. Weird.

I would love to understand this behaviour. I could hack something together that works optically, but a proper fix would be nice.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scriptsize}
\ifoot{foo\parbox[b]{5cm}{baz}}
% or
%\ifoot{foo\parbox[b]{5cm}{bar\\baz}}

\begin{document}
Dummy to produce one page
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, changing `\footskip` (geometry package) has no effect on either the footer or footsepline.  The baseline in this case appears to be ignored and the placement depends on the height, hence the `\smash`.

To horizontally align text, you might be better off using tabular, \makebox, or `\raggedleft`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scriptsize}
\ifoot{\smash{foo\parbox[b]{5cm}{bar\\baz}}}
% or
%\ifoot{foo\parbox[b]{5cm}{bar\\baz}}

\begin{document}
Dummy to produce one page
\end{document}
```